# TypeError: Cannot read property 'allMarkdownRemark' of undefined (In pages)

Tags: javascript, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I am trying to show my markdown data on my about page within the pages folder however the Data prop is undefined.

The allMarkdownRemark query is working as expected in GraphiQL and I can't see anything wrong within the about (I am importing graphql at the top) or MD files. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Github Repo - https://github.com/JackBPainter/portfolio-v2

**GraphiQL**

[image: GraphiQL]

**Gatsby-Config**

[image: Gatsby-Config]

**about.js**

[image: about.js]

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby documentation: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/

You need to execute a query like: (instead data you need to specify as `query`)

```
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allMarkdownRemark {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            last_updated
          }
          html
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Full component:

```
const About = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data)

  return (
    <Layout>
      <StyledAboutContainer>
        <StyledImgContainer>
          <StyledImg src={Face} alt="My Face" />
        </StyledImgContainer>
        <StyledSvgContainer>
          <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 511.999 511.999">
            <path d="M403.073,292.074c-20.817-104.643-108.06-179.475-209.15-189.379l59.398-59.399 c9.905-9.905,9.905-25.962,0-35.867c-9.903-9.905-25.962-9.905-35.867,0L111.808,113.074c-0.003,0.003-0.007,0.008-0.012,0.012 c-0.6,0.602-1.172,1.233-1.709,1.892c-0.247,0.301-0.458,0.622-0.688,0.932c-0.257,0.345-0.526,0.681-0.764,1.04 c-0.318,0.477-0.597,0.969-0.879,1.461c-0.123,0.216-0.264,0.426-0.382,0.646c-0.257,0.48-0.477,0.972-0.7,1.464 c-0.118,0.26-0.25,0.512-0.36,0.776c-0.179,0.428-0.323,0.866-0.475,1.302c-0.122,0.348-0.257,0.693-0.367,1.048 c-0.107,0.353-0.184,0.712-0.274,1.067c-0.117,0.45-0.242,0.896-0.331,1.354c-0.054,0.279-0.085,0.56-0.13,0.839 c-0.088,0.536-0.178,1.069-0.233,1.613c-0.024,0.238-0.024,0.479-0.041,0.719c-0.041,0.577-0.083,1.153-0.083,1.736 c-0.002,0.377,0.036,0.754,0.051,1.131c0.02,0.44,0.02,0.876,0.063,1.317c0.079,0.84,0.205,1.677,0.369,2.509 c0.002,0.007,0.002,0.015,0.003,0.024c0.02,0.1,0.052,0.191,0.074,0.291c0.15,0.719,0.323,1.434,0.538,2.139 c0.078,0.259,0.178,0.504,0.264,0.759c0.181,0.531,0.36,1.062,0.575,1.584c0.142,0.342,0.311,0.668,0.465,0.999 c0.191,0.414,0.377,0.83,0.593,1.234c0.215,0.402,0.458,0.785,0.693,1.173c0.191,0.316,0.37,0.639,0.577,0.947 c0.313,0.468,0.656,0.911,0.998,1.354c0.164,0.213,0.313,0.435,0.485,0.644c0.465,0.568,0.96,1.106,1.471,1.628 c0.073,0.074,0.134,0.156,0.208,0.23l0.037,0.037c0.024,0.024,0.046,0.046,0.069,0.069l105.541,105.543 c4.952,4.954,11.443,7.428,17.933,7.428s12.982-2.477,17.933-7.428c9.905-9.903,9.905-25.962,0-35.867l-65.662-65.664 c79.98,7.265,149.228,66.288,165.662,148.91c2.256,11.34,3.431,22.748,3.566,34.088c0.499,41.582-12.985,82.266-38.472,115.461 c-4.636,6.036-9.666,11.824-15.084,17.326c-9.829,9.981-9.702,26.038,0.277,35.867c4.941,4.864,11.369,7.289,17.792,7.289 c6.557,0,13.11-2.526,18.073-7.568c48.279-49.033,72.508-116,67.505-183.583C406.272,311.253,404.977,301.644,403.073,292.074z" />
          </svg>
        </StyledSvgContainer>
        {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => (
          <StyledH1>{node.frontmatter.title}</StyledH1>
        ))}
      </StyledAboutContainer>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default About

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allMarkdownRemark {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            last_updated
          }
          html
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually had the query specified as query before but it didn't work so tried to mix it up. Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem and data is still coming back as undefined.

Comment: I decided to follow the official gatsby tutorial where they introduced the transformer remark to see if I could get the allMarkDownRemark query to work at all on my application. It all worked as expected with no complications which meant the issue must be with the actual about component itself. I found the problem was actually that about was no longer a gatsby page because I was importing it into index.js

Answer (score 0):

I decided to follow the official gatsby tutorial where they introduced the transformer remark (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-six/) to see if I could get the allMarkDownRemark query to work at all on my application. It all worked as expected with no complications which meant the issue must be with the actual about component itself. I found the problem was actually that about was no longer a gatsby page because I was importing it into index.js